# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'countries'

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxp

### cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'countries'

I am new learner of xml schema validation and found above error
with

### fileSchema.xsd:

```
> <xs:schema version="1.0"
>            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
>            targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ajaxprac"
>            xmlns="http://localhost:8080/ajaxprac"
>            elementFormDefault="qualified">
>     
>     <xs:element name="countries" type="xs:string"/>
>      </xs:schema>
```

### file.xml

```
<countries xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://localhost:8080/ajaxprac"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/ajaxprac fileSchema.xsd">
    This is the xml with just root element
</countries>
```

### Factory Setting

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        f.setValidating(true);
        //f.setNamespaceAware(true);
        try {
            f.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured: "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

I have used 
-test.namespace
-urn:Test.Namespace

instead of `"http://localhost:8080/ajaxprac"`
but facing same error.

Please find the error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. I think it must be something to do with the way you are running the validation: there's nothing wrong with the schema or source document.

Comment: but i am facing the same problem while running the code in neatbeans with this java source code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your example, the only thing you needed to make it run is to uncomment this line:

`//f.setNamespaceAware(true);`

N.B. your mistake helped me :), and I'm happy.